# Polyhedron cut along an edge

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra

By cutting along an edge of a net of a polyhedron, you will form 2 pieces. Are there two distinct polyhedra for which this process may result in the same two pairs of pieces? Is there a real example? I tried to use the platonic solid rules, but later it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Two polyhedra can have the same net.

For example - a regular octahedron and a 'boat' have the same net.

[Boat](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Boat.html)